# DynamoDB: Contains all filter

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a schema with a field called `ids` (list of numbers)

How can I create a `QuerySpec` to filter the items that **contains all** values of a specified list?

For example:

```
item 1: ids=[1,2,3]
item 2: ids=[1,3,5]
```

I need to retrieve only `item 1` when I filter by `[1,2]`

I am using:

`querySpec.withFilterExpression("contains(ids,:f1) and contains(ids,:f2)")`

But I don't know if it is efficient or if there is a more convenient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value cannot be SET, MAP or LIST. You have to use **AND** operator to achieve the result as mentioned in the OP.

> CONTAINS is supported for lists: When evaluating "a CONTAINS b", "a"
>   can be a list; however, "b" cannot be a set, a map, or a list.