# dynamodb scan if an array contains in an other

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of tags and i want get all items that these tags contain.
My code works only with one Tag in the ScanCondition but if i send two tags it throws an exception.

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: 'One or more parameter values were invalid: Invalid number of argument(s) for the CONTAINS ComparisonOperator'

```cs
var scanConditions = new List<ScanCondition>
{
  new ScanCondition("Tags", ScanOperator.Contains, new string[] { "Tag1", "Tag2" })
};

var query = context.ScanAsync<Car>(scanConditions);
var cars = await packageInfos.GetNextSetAsync();
```

My data model

```cs
[DynamoDBTable("Car")]
public class Car
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43874833/1271037

Comment: @dovid it isn`t work, only the first condition is accepted then. If i use multiple scan conditions.

Comment: if you are going to use it in production, please don't do even if you find a way to do so. Scan is not meant to do in active user calls.